# Display Dialog Box When User Meets MaxLength of TextBox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a asp.net C# application.  I have a TextBox that has a MaxLength set of 3000.  When the user reaches the maxlength of 3000 I want a JavaScript dialog box to open and alter the user of this.  I can't figure out how to do it. Can anyone help me?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm re-writing a classic asp application, and it has to function in exactly the same way.  So I'm stuck with it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

From [aspdotnet-suresh](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/02/javascript-show-number-of-characters.html):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Limit the number of characters in textbox or textarea</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function LimtCharacters(txtMsg, CharLength, indicator) 
{
    chars = txtMsg.value.length;
    document.getElementById(indicator).innerHTML = CharLength - chars;
    if (chars > CharLength) 
    {
        txtMsg.value = txtMsg.value.substring(0, CharLength);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:13px">
Number of Characters Left:
<label id="lblcount" style="background-color:#E2EEF1;color:Red;font-weight:bold;">3000</label><br/>
<textarea id="mytextbox" rows="5" cols="25" onkeyup="LimtCharacters(this,3000,'lblcount');"></textarea>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TextChanged` event of your TextBox for this. Inside your handler, you can simply check the length of the `TextBox.Text` property, and display a MessageBox if it reaches the maximum length like so:

```
Response.Write(string.Format("<script>alert('{0}');</script>", message));
```

Comment: I tried this, but couldn't get it work, I'm guessing there's something missing that I don't know what to fill in for.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the number of characters with this JavaScript

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function limitText(Field, limitNum) {
            if (Field.value.length > limitNum) {
                Field.value = Field.value.substring(0, limitNum);
            }
        }
    </script>


<asp:FormView runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <b>Something</b>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" onKeyDown="limitText(this,3000);"
            onKeyUp="limitText(this,3000);"></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Or to Display alert,

```
<input type="text"  onkeydown="return testLength()" id="txtBox" />

function testLength(){
   var e = document.getElementById('txtBox');
   if(e.value.length>6)
   {
      alert('you have entered more than 3000 characters');
      // Set value back to the first 6 characters 
      e.value = e.value.substring(0, 3000);
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: is there no way to do both?

Comment: possible, preventing user is better than displaying an error box. so go with the first option

Comment: I have to display an error box.  I'm re-writing a classic site.  The new one has to perform in exactly the same way that the old one did.